# Remove LongTensor from a set of LongTensors in Python/Pytorch

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch, tensor

I have a set containing some LongTensors and I need to remove some of the LongTensors from the set, is there an efficient way of doing that in pytorch?

```
import torch
ks = {torch.LongTensor([1, 3]), torch.LongTensor([2, 3]), torch.LongTensor([3, 3])}
p = torch.LongTensor([1, 3])
ks.remove(p)
```

The method above returns

> KeyError: tensor([1, 3])

Is there an efficient way of removing the tensor??

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through [list-comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to compare each elements one by one then convert `list` back to `set`.

```py
>>> set([x for x in ks if (x!=p).any()])
{tensor([3, 3]), tensor([2, 3])}
```